# Find Index of the Object inside an Javascript array by the provided Object

Tags: javascript

I want to know about this functionality but can't find any solution in the web.

Below is a dummy array with lot of data like this.

```
var a = [
 {
  "category": "1",
  "title": "Apple",
  "price": 1049
 },
 {
  "category": "2",
  "title": "Mango",
  "price": 2000
 },
 ....So on
]
```

i want to find the index of the object inside this var 'a' Array by the actual object data.
Example i have a object

```
var b =   {
  "category": "2",
  "title": "Mango",
  "price": 2000,
},
```

How to find this? `a.findIndex(b)` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare every property without stringifying.

```js
var a = [
  {
    "category": "1",
    "title": "Apple",
    "price": 1049
  },
  {
    "category": "2",
    "title": "Mango",
    "price": 2000
  },
]

var b = {
  "category": "2",
  "title": "Mango",
  "price": 2000,
};

const index = a.findIndex(o => Object.keys(o).every(key => o[key] == b[key]));

console.log(index); // 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer.  I only used `.some` because I forgot about `.every` and this way is better since it doesn't invert the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the objects after stringifying.

```js
var a = [
 {
  "category": "1",
  "title": "Apple",
  "price": 1049
 },
 {
  "category": "2",
  "title": "Mango",
  "price": 2000
 },
];
var b =   {
  "category": "2",
  "title": "Mango",
  "price": 2000,
}, bStr = JSON.stringify(b);
let idx = a.findIndex(obj=>JSON.stringify(obj)===bStr);
console.log(idx);
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` may be [unnecessarily slow](https://jsbench.me/bvkd99xdb4/1) and it will fail to find the object with different property order.